# Как ускорить скрипт на Python, который удаляет строки в файле, используя список

Tags: python

Подскажите, как можно ускорить скрипт. Суть его такая:

Есть два файла - file1.txt и file2.txt. Из первого файла удаляются строки, номера которых есть во втором файле.

Кусок из file1.txt:

```
STR-227313Я вас любил: любовь еще, быть может,

STR-227314В душе моей угасла не совсем;

STR-227315Но пусть она вас больше не тревожит;

STR-227316Я не хочу печалить вас ничем.

STR-227317Я помню чудное мгновенье:

STR-227318Передо мной явилась ты,

STR-227412Я вас любил безмолвно, безнадежно,

STR-227415То робостью, то ревностью томим;

STR-227417Я вас любил так искренно, так нежно,

STR-227418Как мимолетное виденье,

STR-227419Как дай вам бог любимой быть другим.
```

Кусок из file2.txt:

```
STR-227317
STR-227318
STR-227418
```

Результат:

```
STR-227313Я вас любил: любовь еще, быть может,

STR-227314В душе моей угасла не совсем;

STR-227315Но пусть она вас больше не тревожит;

STR-227316Я не хочу печалить вас ничем.

STR-227412Я вас любил безмолвно, безнадежно,

STR-227415То робостью, то ревностью томим;

STR-227417Я вас любил так искренно, так нежно,

STR-227419Как дай вам бог любимой быть другим.
```

Мой код:

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as file, 
open("file2.txt", "r") as file2, 
open("file_done.txt", "w") as rezult: 
    content1 = file.read() 
    content2 = file2.read() 
    lines1 = content1.splitlines() 
    lines2 = content2.splitlines() 
    i = 0 
    rez = [] 
    while i < len(lines1): 
        key = True 
        for j in range(len(lines2)): 
            if lines2[j] in lines1[i]: 
                key = False 
                i += 1 
                break 
        if key: 
            rez.append(lines1[i]) 
        i += 1 
    rezult.write('\n'.join(rez))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать множества для хранения строк вместо списка.

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as file, \
     open("file2.txt", "r") as file2, \
     open("file_done.txt", "w") as rezult:
     
    lines2 = set(line.strip() for line in file2)
    
    for line in file:
        if line[:9] not in lines2:
            rezult.write(line)
```

Здесь мы используем оператор [:9] для того, чтобы получить первые 9 символов строки, что эквивалентно номеру строки в file2.txt.

Comment: Для полноты картины стоит ещё подсказать ,что делать, если длина номера непостоянна.

Comment: Режим "r" при открытии файла стоит по умолчанию, писать его не обязательно. Бэкслеши в конце строки считаются моветоном.

Comment: Спасибо за пример, работает шустро. Благо в моём случае всегда одинаковая длина номеров (всё таки 10 символов). Только отступы остаются вместо удалённых строк. Подскажите как правильно это исправить в коде?

Comment: Пустые строки тоже отсекайте в if, а после каждой записанной строки ещё пишите пустую.

Comment: @MBo, здравствуйте) подскажите что делать если длина строки не постоянна? Все таки понадобился такой вариант (

Comment: @Alexander Если длина номера может меняться, выделяйте его с помощью регулярного выражения 'STR-\d+'

Comment: @MBo, а как сделать чтобы наоборот первые 10 символов игнорировались, а искалось то что после 10 символов и до конца строки ?

Comment: match.end() даст конец номера, от него и выделяйте подстроку. Или у вас номер так и остался постоянной длины? Срез делайте от нужной позиции до конца

Comment: @MBo да номер остался той же длины, как сделать срез от позиции и до конца строки?

Comment: Вы что, никогда не заглядывали в хелп по срезам? `line[10:]`

Comment: @MBo заглядывал, и line[10:] пробовал, но теперь скрипт вообще будто ничего не находит в files2

Comment: Так у вас же в files2 номера. Вы их ищете там? Если задача сильно изменилась, можно новый вопрос задать, с примером данных и кодом, который сейчас не работает

Comment: @MBo сейчас во втором файле не просто номера. После номеров идёт текст (примерно как в files1), по которому надо делать поиск в files1. То есть сейчас текст в файле1 и файле2 примерно одинаков, но нужно совершить поиск игнорируея номера, то есть по тексту, брать текст из второго файла и искать текст (игнорируя номера) в первом

Comment: Давайте новый вопрос, в комментариях это уже лишнее

Comment: Вероятно, вам поможет создание set из обрезанных строк из 2

Comment: @MBo создал новый вопрос

Comment: Вы создали ответ, а не вопрос, его нужно удалить. Предыдущий мой комментарий пробовали реализовать? lines2 = set(line.strip()[10:] for line in file2)

Comment: @MBo пробовал. Скрипт просто копирует содержимое 1 файла , будто во втором файле нет ничего

Comment: Кстати, создание множества в ответе можно сделать чуть короче и красивее: `lines2 = set(map(str.strip, file2))`.

Comment: Ну разбирайтесь, что у вас попадает в set - выводите на отладочную печать

Comment: @MBo хорошо, спасибо вам за ответы